# Order list of articles by Date

Tags: asp.net, archive

I am trying to create a page, named `Archive.aspx`, that displays all my articles ordered by date. something like this:

```
February 2012

17: Name of article  
10: Name of article 2

January 2012

20: Name of article 3  
12: Name of article 4
```

I tried with this code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="artid" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <h1><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("artdate","{0:MMMM yyyy}") %>' /></h1>
            <li style="">
                <asp:Label ID="artdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("artdate","{0:dd}") %>' />:
                <asp:LinkButton ID="titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#Bind("artid","Articol.aspx?art={0}") %>' />

            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <li style="">
                <asp:Label ID="artdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("artdate","{0:dd}") %>' />:
                <asp:LinkButton ID="titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#Bind("artid","Articol.aspx?art={0}") %>' />
            </li>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No data was returned.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                <li ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </ul>
                <div style="">
                </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT  [artid], [title], [artdate] FROM [as_Articles] ORDER BY [artdate] DESC">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But, I do not get the result that I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are wanting grouped records, you will need to do nested binding: http://leedumond.com/blog/nested-listviews-and-more-working-with-databound-controls-inside-the-listview/